# 私は米国人です vs 私はアメリカ人です

Tags: words

They both mean `I am an American` but which is preferable in everyday speech and in writing, and why? Is the former more formal than the latter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Today people never say `米国人` in everyday speech and even in written form most people express American as `アメリカ人`.

The obvious exception is on a newspaper. Writers there still express it as `米国人`, for possibly two reasons:

1. `米国` is shorter than `アメリカ`.
2. Kanji is more suited than Katakana to vertical writing, which is still used in newspapers.

I also want to note that this tends to be applied to `英国`/`イギリス` as well. Also, Kanji is often used to express each country (e.g. `仏`, `独`, or `伊` to express `フランス`, `ドイツ`, or `イタリア`) even on the web news just because those are shorter.

Answer (score 7):

Honestly, I have almost always heard people from the United States use "アメリカ人". I think "米国"　can indeed be thought as more formal, and is used a lot when it comes to guidebooks and such. I see it a lot in writing, and when writing compounds:

- 米文学｛べいぶんがく｝: American literature. Any other form, 米国 or アメリカ, can be used there.
- 北米｛ほくべい｝: North America
- 米州｛べいしゅう｝： The Americas

Keep in mind that they both have exactly the same meaning: the United States of America.

- 米国{べいこく} comes from 亜米利加｛あめりか｝ which is I think simply a juxtaposition of Chinese characters to get the actual sound.
- Similarly, for France, フランス is always used in katakana except for French - Japanese dictionaries for which the chinese character 仏｛ふつ｝ is used. This one comes from 仏蘭西｛ふらんす｝. However, this only used when referring to "abstract" France, and never to refer to the country or to the people. You can also find it for example in the 仏検｛ふつけん｝, the French proficiency test for Japanese people.
- For the English language, 英｛えい｝ is used, but this one comes from England, 英国｛えいこく｝,　which itself is from 英吉利｛いぎりす｝.

So, they are the same but I tend to hear a lot more of "アメリカ" and see a lot of "米国" written. If you have a look on Wikipedia though, you can see most pages that have 米 in their name are redirected to their アメリカ counterparts which would seem to indicate that アメリカ would even be more correct or at least more frequent.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, my 在留カード issued by the Japanese government says 米国. And the tax treaty I benefit from says アメリカ合衆国 which is the formal name of the United States of America in Japanese. I say this just in regards to the "more correct" aspect.

Comment: Thanks for the insight... Being a non-american, I never really encountered the various aspects of the name of the country.

Comment: The Americas in English wouldn't refer to just the USA; it'd include all the land in North and South American continents.  Does it really just refer to the USA in Japan?

Comment: I don't think Urukann is saying *the Americas* refers specifically to the United States.  He's just giving examples using 米.